# Autenticação Laravel 5 não exibe erros

Tags: laravel

Boa tarde, estou utilizando o Laravel 5 para refazer um sistema e na tela de login quando não é feita a autenticação o usuário é redirecionado para o formulário novamente mas não consigo retornar nenhum erro.

**Model User**

```
protected $connection = 'pgsql2';
protected $primaryKey = 'cod_funcionario';
public $timestamps = false;
protected $table = 'funcionarios';
protected $fillable = ['login', 'senha'];
protected $hidden = ['senha', 'remember_token'];

public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->senha;
}

public function setSenhaAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['senha'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```

**AuthController.php**

```
protected $redirectPath = '/admin';
protected $loginPath = '/admin/auth/login';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}

protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => $data['password'],
        //'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}

public function postAdminLogin()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['login' => Request::input('login'), 'password' => Request::input('senha')]))
    {

        return redirect()->intended('admin');
    }
    else{
        return Redirect::to('admin/auth/login');

}
```

e na view estou tentando exibir os erros da seguinte forma:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{!! $error !!}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Amigo, poste o código que já tem, irá ajudar e MUITO á te ajudarem rs.

Comment: Postei, se precisar de mais algum.

Comment: Veja a resposta que postei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso geralmente eu uso `Session`.

Por exemplo, deu erro de login, faça isso no seu `else`.

```
else{
     Session::flash('alert', 'Deu pau no login, tente de novo');
      return Redirect::to('admin/auth/login');
}
```

Daí na página de login eu coloco, se for blade, se não for usa o normal do PHP mesmo.

```
@if(Session::has('alert'))
    {!! Session::get('alert') !!}
@endif
```

Este `Session::flash` funciona apenas de uma página para a outra. Top, né ?

Não.

Comment: Obrigado, desta forma funcionou.

Comment: Marque como a resposta certa se te ajudou mesmo.